# SharePoint WCF SOAP, Rest, AJAX

Tags: client-object-model, reporting-services, wcf, ajax

I need to know the following things:

1. How is SharePoint used with WCF, REST and SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint uses WCF through web services. SharePoint's web services surfaces a wide variety of data including lists, user information, sites, alerts, forms, search, webparts, etc. all can use CRUD operations. This is built on top of WCF. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193051(v=office.15).aspx) for more info.

REST is another technology that SharePoint 2013 allows to surface data for CRUD operations. It allows a more robust process that is easily integrated with Javascripts and client-side code. It's process is more current, as web services are becoming outdated. Along with OData, REST with SharePoint can be a inexpensive and powerful tool to allow data surfacing and manipulation. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx) for more info

SOAP is used mainly with SharePoint web services, BCS (indirectly), and Excel Web Services to surface Excel data. SOAP is depreciated in SharePoint 2013 and future versions, and users are encouraged to use REST API, CSOM, and JSOM to get data from SharePoint.